# Pyomo: Can we set up a param with empty index?

Tags: pyomo

can we set up param with an empty index? For example:

```
self.param_A = pyo.Param(
     self.INDEX_1, # this INDEX_1 is generated elsewhere and could be empty in some cases
     within=pyo.NonNegativeReals
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The same applies to variables, constraints, expressions and so on.